# SCORM 1.2 CMI Objectives

Tags: scorm1.2

Some SCO set the cmi.objectives.XXx.  Other content does not.  If I look inside the imsmanifest.xml files, does it tells me if the SCO is setting the cmi.objectives.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only tell what objectives the content is going to report by waiting for them to come in during runtime. In SCORM 2004, you can look to see if any objectives are defined in the manifest, but the content is still free to report additional objectives.

The best way to find the list of objectives reported by the content is probably to run it through [SCORM Cloud](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud/) and then either look at the debug log or the registration state to see what was reported.